# Use gensim Random Projection in sklearn SVM

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf, gensim

Is it possible to use a gensim Random Projection to train a SVM in sklearn?
I need to use `gensim`'s tfidf implementation because it's better at dealing with large inputs and then want to put that into a random projection on which I will train my SVM. I'd also be happy to just pass the tfidf model generated by `gensim` to `sklearn` and use their random projection, if that makes things easier.
But so far I haven't found a way to get either model out of gensim into sklearn.

I have tried using `gensim.matutils.corpus2csc`but of course that doesn't work: neither TfidfModel nor RpModel are corpi, so now I'm clueless at what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

This is now very easy thanks to an awesome `gensim` contribution from Chinmaya Pancholi ([see post here](https://rare-technologies.com/chinmayas-gsoc-2017-summary-integration-with-sklearn-keras-and-implementing-fasttext/)).

Simply import the `sklearn` wrapper from `gensim:

```
from gensim.sklearn_api import RpTransformer
```

Then, you can use the model to do analysis as you would any other sklearn classifier:

```
model = RpTransformer(num_topics=2)
clf = svm.SVC()
pipe = Pipeline([('features', model,), ('classifier', clf)])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

One thing to be aware of, when using the `gensim` models, is that you still need to perform the `dictionary` and `corpus` steps. So instead of fitting your model on `X_train`, you'll have to do something along the following lines:

```
dictionary = Dictionary(X_train)
corpus_train = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in X_train]
corpus_test = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in X_test]
```

Then fit/predict your model on `corpus_train` or `corpus_test`.